# AWS OpenSearch 2.8.0 Creat

Tags: opensearch

When I installed it and tried to start it, I encountered the following errors:

"SSL dual mode is disabled"
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to load plugin class [org.opensearch.security.OpenSearchSecurityPlugin]"

From my understanding, it seems that SSL is disabled, but the OpenSearchSecurityPlugin cannot be loaded.

I attempted to set "plugins.security.ssl.transport.enabled: false" and restart it manually, but the issue persisted. Based on the error message, it appears that SSL must be enabled ("plugins.security.ssl.transport.enabled: true") for it to work.

Could someone with more experience provide guidance on this issue?

I attempted to set "plugins.security.ssl.transport.enabled: false"